How to handle questions of the form "Find all entire functions such that... "
I apologize if this is not the right forum to ask this question. Could you please recommend an online lecture, a textbook note to refer to understand how to answer questions of the form
Find all entire functions such that "satisfying a certain condition".
I have refer questions such as this (in the positive direction) and this (in the negative direction)

I think that would simply be a textbook in complex analysis.

Not every textbook treats this type of question, hence why I asked the question. I know it has to do with entire (analytic everywhere in the finite complex plane) functions but I'm particularly curious on how to approach these type of questions.

At first impression the linked questions seem typical. The first uses Liouville's theorem and generalizations (an entire function $f$ satisfying $|f(z)| \leq |z|^\alpha$ for some positive $\alpha$ is a polynomial of degree at most $\alpha$). The second uses the identity principle: two entire functions agreeing on a set with a limit point agree everywhere. Are you seeking an answer in greater scope and/or detail?

@AndrewD.Hwang, thank you for your comment. Yes, I'm seeking how to approach to such a question in general.
